# Partial template specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to specialise the constructor of the following templated class

```
enum class A { a1, a2 };
enum class B { b1, b2 };

template<typename A, typename B>
class test
{
public:
    test(A a, B b) {}
};
```

How would I specialise the constructor to take a *particular* value of B, such as B::b1? I've not tried this before, and the following did not work.

```
template<typename A>
class test<A, B::b1> {};
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: `template<typename A, typename B>`, here A and B are unrelated to your enum... Do you want `template<A a, B b>` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second parameter of template `test` only accepts a ***type*** (like `B`), instead of a ***value*** (`B::b1`). `test<A, B::b1>` is always ill-formed whatever you do to specialize `test`.

however, you can build a mapping from a value to a type, such as:

```cpp
enum class A { a1, a2 };
enum class B { b1, b2 };

template<typename A, typename B>
class test{
public:
    test(A a, B b) {}
};

template<typename T, T v>
class tag{};

template<typename A, typename T, T v>
class test<A, tag<T, v>>{};

using example = test<A, tag<B, B::b1>>;
```

Comment: With C++17, you might have `template <auto v> struct tag{};`.